# How to kick someone off my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am giving free internet to my friends and neighbor's also because I have guest mode feature on my Tp-link c20. But I don't want some people to connect to it - I don't like them. They seem to have MAC randomized on their phone, they just reconnect with different MAC address when I block them.
And someone from my friends side gave that person my new password to piss me off. What can I do?

Comment: Your only choice in this situation is to stop sharing your internet.  Disable the guest network.  Change your password.  Voting to close this question since it seems to be more of a social problem that needs to be solved rather than a technical one.

Comment: Agreeing with Ramhound. Maybe, change the password and don't give it to your friend? It's the more sane approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of blacklisting people you don't like, enable
Wireless MAC Filtering on the router and include in the whitelist all
your devices, excluding all others.

Disable MAC Filtering when you have guests, or include their MAC address
in the permitted list.

See the
[Archer C20 V5 User Guide](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/Archer-C20_V5/),
section "6.4. Wireless MAC Filtering".